# Why Do I Get an Unlicensed Assemblies Error Message at Run Time When Using Measurement Studio .NET Controls in a Visual C# Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, runtime, measurement

I am using NI Measurement Studio 2012 free evaluation under Visual Studio 2008 express and Windows XP.

My problem is the following:

I can compile my C# solution without problems but in run time I get an unlicensed assembly error message related to PropertyEditor when trying to instantiate this:

new PropertyEditor();

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the .lic files are missing.  Maybe this might help: http://joule.ni.com/nidu/cds/view/p/id/3064/lang/en

Comment: I have checked if license files are in the correct path, and they are. Anyway, I have downloaded again them from the link you provide me but it does not work. NI license manager says: [Debug Deployment - Status: Unactivated license file. Activation is required for the licensed version]; [Enterprise Development - Status: For evaluation only. Activation is required for the licensed version]; and the rest [Professional Development], [Standard Development] their status figures the same as Debug Deployment.

Comment: I don't think so as it is an evaluation version for 7 days and I have downloaded and installed today. Anyway, how can I Know if license is expired apart from seeing ît through NI license manager?

Comment: I think I have solved: By drag and drop a PropertyEditor control from Visual Studio toolbox to form in design view, licenses.licx is updated, and then unlicensed message is not shown in run time. Once licenses.licx file updated, you can remove PropertyEditor control from design (if you only want do it programmatically).